# Moving Windows Users Home directorys

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am looking for suggestions on moving 2000+ users home directories and profiles from a Windows server 2003 DC box to our new Server 2012 DC box? How can I keep directory rights intact and move the file structure? I am in a higher education environment.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! There appears to be little to no research done on this issue up front.  It is recommended that you post things you've already tried, options you are considering, or errors that you are experiencing.  The more details you provide, the better the experts here can assist you.

Comment: Use [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Robocopy with the [correct options](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

```
robocopy /timfix /mir /zb /purge /copyall S:\source d:\destination
```

Comment: Not sure why the down vote on this. `robocopy` is available on 2012 by default and does what the OP wants.

Comment: @jscott, my initial version of this question didn't include the example.  My copy-paste failed, and I didn't notice it.  Someone rushed to judgement.